Notion of distance for points lying outside of a manifold and in an ambient space
I am trying to understand how to extend the notion of distance for a given Riemannean manifold (M, g) lying in an ambient space X. I am thinking of the following $d_M$:
$$d_M(x, y) = d(x, M) + d(x_{proj}, y_{proj}) + d(y, M)$$
where $x_{proj}$ is the projection of $x$ on $M$ and $y_{proj}$ is similarly defined. and d(x, M) is the length of projection of x onto M. additionally $d(x_{proj}, y_{proj})$ a distance on manifold.  I apologize if my understanding has inconsistencies. Differential geoemtry is by no means a strength but something I am trying to use to formalize my intuition.
UPDATE:
Based on the answer and comments by @MoisheKohan, I'll add the following:
The reason I assumed M is a manifold, was that in my partiuclar case I have a measure of this manifold, and additionally I am relying on diffusion random walks as defining a loose sense of metric. Essentially my goal is to extend a metric defined on M to a metric defined on X, but assuring that points that are too far from the manifold are gonna have higher distances.

The trouble is that there can be more than one projection.

This has very little to do with Riemannian geometry and is a metric geometry question. There are two issues with your idea: The (nearest point) projection might not exist and it also need not be unique. The first issue is less serious (one just needs to work with minimizing sequences) and I will be assuming that $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $M\subset X$ is a subset such that for every $x\in X$ there exists at least one point $\bar{x}\in M$ realizing the minimal distance $d(x,M)$. Let $P(x)\subset M$ denote the subset consisting of such points $\bar x$. To get an example of nonuniqueness, consider the Euclidean plane $(X,d)$ and $M\subset X$ which is a circle centered at the origin $o$.
The assumption that $M$ is a Riemannian submanifold is essentially irrelevant, below, I will assume that $M$ is a subset of $X$ equipped with some metric $d_M$. Then for $x, y\in X$ one can define
$$
d^M(x,y)= \inf \{d(x, \bar{x}) + d_M(\bar{x}, \bar{y}) + d(y, \bar{y}): \bar{x}\in P(x), \bar{y}\in P(y)\}. 
$$
It is clear that:

$d^M(x,y)=0\Rightarrow x=y$.

$d^M(x,y)=d^M(y,x)$.

$d^M(x,y)=d_M(x,y)$ for all $x, y\in M$.


It is a nice exercise to verify the triangle inequality. However, unless $x\in M$, $d^M(x,x)=2d(x, P(x))>0$. Hence, $d^M$ is only a metametric.

Thanks so much @moishekohan. The reason I assumed M is a manifold, was that in my partiuclar case I have a measure of this manifold, and additionally I am relying on diffusion random walks as defining a loose sense of metric. Essentially my goal is to extend a metric defined on M to a metric defined on X, but assuring that points that are too far from the manifold are gonna have higher distances. But all these insights were quite helpful. Thank you!

@Cupitor: The manifold assumption makes no difference.
